# Trigger a custom function when option are saved in admin area

Tags: functions, hooks, admin, actions

I am creating a Wordpress theme from scratch and I would like to save a file with the theme option anytime the theme options change.

I was thinking about:

```
do_action('admin_init', 'my_custom_function');
function my_custom_function(){
    save_file();
    ...
}
```

but in this case the file will be save anytime the admin area is loaded.

On the dashboard the theme creates forms to manage the theme options, like the following:

```
<form method="post" action="options.php">

    <?php settings_fields( 'theme-settings-group' ); ?>
    <?php do_settings_sections( 'theme-settings-group' ); ?>

    // form in here
    <?php submit_button(); ?>

</form>
```

This form send information to options.php which save the theme options on the database based on the setting group specified.

I would like to trigger an function any time something is saved in "options.php".

Can you guys suggest please?
Thannks

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. WordPress has a special API for themes to store options which I do not currently understand well enough to explain but others do. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

**update_option_{option_name}**: Runs after the option with name "option_name" has been updated. For example, for the option with name "foo":

```
 add_action('update_option_foo', 'my_custom_function', 10, 2);
```

**update_option**: Runs before an option gets updated. Example:

```
add_action('update_option', 'my_custom_function', 10, 3);
```

**updated_option**: Runs after an an option has been updated. Example:

```
add_action('updated_option', 'my_custom_function', 10, 3);
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that the hooks `updated_option` and `update_option_{$option}` which run after tan option has been saved, will not fire if the value of the option is the same as the previously saved ones. Some suggest to use `pre_update_option_{$option}` however this hook is fires just before the values have been updated into the database which might not work depending on your callback needs.